# How to Load Data into Gulp dynamically?

Tags: gulp

One of my job duties is to build email newsletter.  The process is my supervisor picks the products and send these to me in email. Then I use gulp to automatically load all the producs' link data into the template HTML file(use Swig). The problem is every time,I have to copy and paste the product link into data file.Is there a way to load the data into data file when other people choose the products through online forms? These forms maybe are built in the WordPress or any other suggestions?

Here's my data file.

```
module.exports={
campaign:'20170217 - S&W - M&P2.0',
siteURL :'http://defenderoutdoors.com/',
offers: [
        {index:'1',link:'152651-smith-wesson-11524'},
        {index:'2',link:'g-outdoors-1411mrb-range-bag'},
        {index:'3',link:'143977-kershaw-knives-1301bw'},
        {index:'4',link:'146950-streamlight-69262'},
        {index:'5',link:'140481-american-tactical-imports-rkt03'},
        {index:'6',link:'wolf-wpa-military-classic-223-rem-62-gr-hp-20rd-mc22362hpbx'},
        {index:'7',link:'smith-and-wesson-and-wesson-23'},
        {index:'8',link:'remington-1500-22lr-40gr-hv-plated-lrn'}
]};
```

Here's my gulp file:

```
var gulp=require('gulp'),
rename=require('gulp-rename'),
swig=require('gulp-swig')
data=require('gulp-data'),
context=require('./dev/test-data.js');

gulp.task('render',function(){
return gulp.src('./dev/template.html')
.pipe(data(context))
.pipe(swig({defaults:{cache:false}}))
.pipe(rename('preview.html'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dev')); });
```